# Wordpress Custom Search Form within a page

Tags: wordpress

I need to add a custom search form within a page, and the search form results should return/highlight items within that page..

ex..

in a page:
monkey
pig
tree

when a user searches for 'pig'

it'll either display only 'pig' or highlight the word pig.

I thought of using custom query but I realized it'll display the whole content instead of the actual text/searched item itself.

Comment: Consider posting this on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can highlight your search results with a few simple steps. For this solution your theme needs to have a search.php file. If it does, follow these simple steps:

Open the search.php file and find `<?php the_title(); ?>`

Replace that with this:

```
<?php echo $title; ?>
```

Now you'll need to place this bit of code before the title tag you just changed (anywhere before should work, just be sure not to place it inside an open

```
<?php 
  $title = get_the_title(); 
  $keys= explode(" ",$s); 
  $title = preg_replace('/('.implode('|', $keys) .')/iu', '<strong class="search-keywords">\0</strong>', 
  $title); 
?>
```

What that code does is add a class to the title or in this case the results of the search. The class in my example is .search-keywords. Now you need to open your themes style.css file and add some styles to it. Here is an example (change it however you need:

```
.search-keywords {
  background:yellow;
  color:blue;
  }
```